# what is the fastest way to find similar records from different (big) data sources

Tags: architecture, algorithm

I work for a public health agency that has lots of different demographic datasets--stored in SQL sever, Access and Excel. I've written an application that allows people to find 'matches' in those datasets based on different criteria, set up with a GUI. For instance, one 'match' might be that the First, Last and DOB match in both datasets--but the SSN is 'off by 1' (determined by the Levenshtein algorithm).

These are big datasets. The matching criteria can get really complex. Right now, I find matches by pulling both datasets into data tables in memory and then going row-by-row through the first table and seeing if there are any rows in the second table that match (using LINQ). So my code looks something like:

```
For each table1Row in TableOne/DatasourceOne
    table2Options=from l in table2rows where Levenshtein(table1Row.first, l.first)<2 //first name off by one            
    table2Options=from l in table2rows where Levenshtein(table1Row.last, l.last)<2 //last name off by one 
    if table2Options.count>1 then the row in table1 'matches' table 2      
Next
```

The code produces the correct output (finds matches) but it is SLOOOW. I know that going row-by-row is supposed to be slower--but using LINQ to find all the records all at once goes even slower.

```
From l in table1, k in table2 where Levenshtein(l.first, k.first)<2 and Levenshtein(l.last, k.last)<2 select l //this takes forever because it calculates the function for l rows * k rows
```

Any ideas on how to do this core matching faster?

Comment: Would it be possible to cache the top *n* combinations of `table1Row.first, l.first` and `table1Row.last, l.last` with their related data so for those cases, you only have to search through the cache data and not the full table? You'd probably have to do some usage analysis to see if this would make sense in your case.

Comment: Consolidate your data. OR run a nightly job to calculate potential matches and store those results in one of your data sources and then look up that instead of calculating on the fly.  RBAR (row by agonizing row) operations are notoriously slow.

Comment: Thanks guys--but unfortunately caching solutions won't work. The whole point is to allow matching between unexpected datasources. I'm looking for a way around RBAR, but am not sure if there is a way around it because I need to calculate the levenshtein function for each possible combination

Comment: This question may be better suited, and get better answeres over at SO.

Comment: @JonRaynor - Agreed, he needs to get all his data into one database.  Especially since he has unencrypted/decryptable SSNs - the fewer places those are referenced, the better.

Comment: @X-Zero: Agreed! But lots of the datasets come from other organizations and agencies. The whole reason we need to run these 'matches' is to see if they are already in our programs

Comment: My comment is a suggestion only, please take it as such.  If you can export the data from these data sources and then BCP into SQL server stages tables and run your process, it might be better.  Even Access and Excel can export.  Whether or not this is possible or if you external data sources are willing to do this is another story.  :)  Did you roll your own algorithim?  I found this link with the fastest implementation.  http://www.levenshtein.net/levenshtein_implementation.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Possible_improvements) on Levenshtein cites a number of possible improvements that should help.  In your case, since you are only interested in distances below a threshold, you should note that if the strings are equal size (such as in social security numbers), you can use the hamming distance instead.  For strings of unequal size you only need to compute a diagonal stripe of 2k+1 in the matrix, where k is your threshold.

Running two lists of strings against each other should be able to provide some optimizations in the Levenshtein algorithm.  For example, comparing replacements for a word that begins with 'a' will apply to *all* words that begin with 'a'.  I'll see if I can come up with a reference algorithm that already optimizes this way.

Comment: Thanks Karl. I have already tinkered some with the Levenshein to optimize it. My implementation takes a 'greater than' parameter. If the distance between the strings is greater than the parameter, it outputs 1000 for distance. Also, for values in the diagonal down the matrix it quits early and returns 1000 if it finds that levenshtein distance computed thus far is greater than the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

**Add and If Statement to not check `FirstName` if `LastName` does not Match..**

99% of the `LastName`s won't match.. so you will rarely perform the check on first name. *This will cut your processing time in almost half.*

---

Another thing you can do is add more rules, (of course you must do this while keeping the bushiness intent intact).. for example: if you if you add a rule to say "The first letter of the `LastName` must match", you then can  filter by this first, thereby giving you a tremendous boost in efficacy.

Comment: Thanks @Morons. I'm already doing what you suggest. Those Table2 options are each a narrowing of the possibilities. The second time table 2 options is polled, it has already eliminated the non-first hits.

Comment: Oh.. Well you can still reverse the order to do LastName First :). That should help somewhat...

Answer (score 1):

Could you bring all the data you need to analyse in to memory, then analyse it? I've replaced code like this:

```
for each day in months:
     for each customer in customers:
          computed = computeSalesInDatabase(customer,day)
          saveComputed(computed)
```

With code like this:

```
for each day in months:
     dailyData = getFullDay(day)
     for each customer in customers:
          computed = computeSalesInMemory(customer,day,dailyData)
          saveComputed(computed)
```

And found it to be more performant.

Comment: Do you mean cache the computed values/calculate them ahead of time? Or calculate all the values at the start and then use them? Both of those solutions don't help much because (1) I don't know what matches will be asked for ahead of time (2) There are way, way, way too many values to calculate to calculate them all/store them all in ram.

Comment: Upon re-reading your post (have you added information?) my above suggestion really doesn't seem like much help, sounds like you are already doing a bit of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at moving this toward some kind of No-SQL type implementation. You might want to look at this StackOverflow article on [NoSQL and Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net) for more info.

If you aren't able to go with a full NoSQL implementation, then you might want to take some ideas from it, such as working with key-value pairs to form connections between the data.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would a NoSQL solution be better here?

Comment: @jcolebrand - I was thinking along the lines of having something that would be a scalable solution when it comes to big sets of data with complex querying requirements that need to be done quickly.

Comment: but unless you're just offloading a shitton of calculations, then this is not the faster method. An optimized MS SQL instance or Oracle configuration would be just as fast, I assure you.

Comment: @jcolebrand - It will depend a lot on the nature of the data and the complexity of the searches. I've been working with some medical document processing tests where it does better than some previous techniques I've used. It may not be better but it's worth investigating to see if it is a good fit or if there are algorithmic ideas that can be borrowed.